# Create multiple object looping over array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So i have an array which stores hobbies for each user in an array within the object..

```
var hobbies = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "hobbies": []
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "hobbies": [
      "football"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "hobbies": [
      "football",
      "basketball"
    ]
  }
]
```

What i want to return is a new array of objects but each hobby separated into their own object like below.

```
var result = [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "hobby": "football"
  },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "hobby": "football"
  },
 {
    "id": 3,
    "hobby": "basketball"
  }
]
```

What is have so far is

```
hobbies.filter((f, i) => f.hobbies.length > 0).map((p, i) => {
    while (i < p.hobbies.length) {
 return { id : p.id, hobby : p.hobbies[i] };
}
  });
```

which only returns

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "hobby": "football"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "hobby": "basketball"
  }
]
```

Comment: By the looks of it you are using a relational approach here. Why? Javascript is not a relational DB, no need to reference foreign ids. Just attach a `hobbies` property to each `user` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `array#map`. Iterate through each object and then iterate through each hobby of `hobbies` and create the object.

```js
var hobbies = [ { "id": 1, "hobbies": [] }, { "id": 2, "hobbies": [ "football" ] }, { "id": 3, "hobbies": [ "football", "basketball" ] } ],
    result = hobbies.reduce((r, {id, hobbies}) => r.concat(hobbies.map(hobby => ({id, hobby}))), []);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works well with what I was trying to achieve, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know, "functional" programming is considered "cool" around these parts, however, have you considered using simple loops to, well, loop over your data?

```
let result = [];

for (let {hobbies, id} of data)
    for (let hobby of hobbies)
        result.push({id, hobby})
```

In my opinion, this is far more readable than any `reduce` spaghetti one could come up with ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use inner-loop to loop through the hobbies and push them one-by-one to the target array:

```js
var hobbies = [{
    "id": 1,
    "hobbies": []
  },

  {
    "id": 2,
    "hobbies": [
      "football"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "hobbies": [
      "football",
      "basketball"
    ]
  }
];

var result = hobbies.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item.hobbies.forEach(hobby => {
    acc.push({
      id: item.id,
      hobby: hobby
    });
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var hobbies = [{"id": 1,"hobbies": []},{"id": 2,"hobbies": ["football"]},{"id": 3, "hobbies": ["football","basketball"]}];

var res = hobbies.reduce((m, o) => (o.hobbies.forEach(h => m.push({id: o.id, hobby: h})), m), []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need nested loops and this is the basics of it:

You first need to loop over the main `hobbies` array.

Then for each item in the array (which represents a person), you want to loop through their hobbies, and for each one of those hobbies, you need to push an object made up of the profile ID and the hobby into `results` array I created earlier.

```js
var hobbies = [{ "id": 1, "hobbies": [] }, { "id": 2, "hobbies": [ "football" ] }, { "id": 3, "hobbies": [ "football", "basketball" ] } ];

let result = [];

hobbies.forEach(function(profile){
  profile.hobbies.forEach(function(hobby){
    result.push(
            {
        "id": profile.id,
        "hobby": hobby
      }
    );
  });
});

console.log(result)
```

Update: the other answers with Array.reduce (a more specialised loop) will cut the above code down even further.